# Is it correct to say "May I get the reason"

Tags: grammar

Can we say "May I get the reason"? Does it give correct message to user? please reply.

Comment: *May I know the reason?* is better (because you raise the level of the language). However, I'd advise you to use it with care. Saying that in the wrong tone or write that in the wrong context could be taken the wrong way by your listener or your reader.

Comment: "Why?" would be more economical, though without context it's hard to just pick a favourite.

Comment: In addition to *May I know...* per Damkerng T, you could say: *May I ask why?* which is less likely to irk someone in a position of authority who may not want to tell you the reason.   *Aye aye, captain! May I ask why?* won't do :)

Comment: May I have the reason?  Is closest to how you have phrased things.  Depending on the situation, more politeness may be required: If it wouldn't be too much trouble, may I ask why (or why you did not) decided on this course of action?  Without more context about the reason and why you were denied, it is hard to say what the correct response would be for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The word "get" has a lot of meanings. 
Get= know. 
Get=understand. 
You had better say,  May I know the reason? 
This is suitable sentence.
This can be fluently gotten by learners or listeners.

Answer (score 1):

"May I *have* the reason" is the more common phrase in AmE. It's clear that the speaker is requesting something from the listener.

To "get" information implies looking up the info or asking a third party, perhaps for the listener's benefit.